# How many days of inactivity before Bitizens leave?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Given the lack of end-game content, I'm starting to play less. I have heard that Bitizens may leave your Death Star automatically if you do not play for a certain number of days, which would screw up some of my 3-star businesses. Is this true, does this happen after a certain number of days of not playing and, if so, how many days?

Comment: Is that true?  Where did you read about it?

Comment: I remember seeing people discuss it in some comments on those other "Tips for Tiny Death Star" sites or posts, but I can't find it now.  Seems really crummy to get punished for not playing, especially if you spent a lot of time building it up. Guess the first step is to determine if this has happened to anyone. I'll update the question if I find the source again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tested this on my iPhone and I do not think this is true.   I know the game has some anti-cheating features in it, but I set my phone to **airplane mode**, launched the game, closed the game, changed the time on my phone from today (1/20/2014) to a future date (2/15/15) and then relaunched the game.  I was awarded coins for all of the products that have sold in the simulated 391 days, but I **did not lose any bitizens** for the simulated inactivity.

This would make me believe that there is no penalty for being inactive.

Comment: *sets it back to normal* .... [annnnnnddddd airlock accident](http://i.imgur.com/v0HW6xU.png) :(

Comment: This seems as good a test as any, although I've always wondered if they wait till you jump back before the "accident" happens. Going to consider this answered then. Also, condolences to you and the family of Tycho Piett - hope he wasn't doing his dream job. :)